# inheritance nodejs bookshelf model

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have a very simple User model in a node library

```
var User = function (data) {
  this.data = data;
}

User.prototype.data = {}

User.prototype.get = function (name) {
  return this.data[name];
}

exports.User = User;
```

And in my app, I also have a User model extending bookshelf.model

```
var Bookshelf = require(__dirname + "/../bookshelf");

var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'users',
  hasTimestamps: true,

})

module.exports = User;
```

I would like the User model of my app to inherit from the User class of my User library. I cannot find a way to make it work. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I don't think you can do that but you can define a bookshelf base model with no table and those same attributes in the prototype or class parameters of extend and extend that model to your hearts content